# Est-ce qu’il y a risque de confusion dans les phrases suivantes sous l’angle de la reprise de l’information?

Tags: formulation, reformulation, pronom-de-reprise

Est-ce qu’il y a risque de confusion quant au référant auquel le pronom de reprise est attaché?

Exemple 1:
Jean-Daniel n'a jamais pu supporter la personnalité excentrique de Bruno. Celui-ci a tendance à toujours tout exagérer.

- *Celui-ci* n’est-il pas supposé reprendre le nom le plus récemment mentionné? À en croire l’auteur, cette phrase présente un risque de confusion.

Exemple 2:
Jean est parti chercher Jacques avec ma voiture. La sienne est au garage.

- Qu’est-ce qui assure que *la sienne* renvoie à la voiture de Jean? À mon sens *la sienne* pourrait tout aussi bien reprendre la voiture de Jacques. Selon l’auteur, cette phrase serait claire et il n’y aurait aucun risque d’ambiguïté.

N’hésitez pas à me proposer d’autres tournures qui permettent de se passer d’interrogations quant à la reprise de l’information

**Celui-ci, celle-ci**, désignent l'être ou la chose les plus proches (fonction déictique) ou **représentent le nom le plus récemment exprimé** ou qui va être développé (fonction anaphorique), par opposition à celui-là, celle-là-Larousse

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/celui/14040

Comment: — 1 - L'ambiguïté vient de l'origine de l'exaspération : *“personnalité excentrique”* -> la référence à la phrase précédente aurait dû être ***celle-là***, l'ambigüité viendrait qu'elle est précédée par Jean-Daniel — 2 - Il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté, la voiture qui roule est celle du locuteur : elle ne peut être conduite que par Jean puisque que c'est Jacques qui sera transporté.

Comment: 2- Mais…Jacques aurait pu être transporté puisque sa voiture « la sienne » est au garage, non? Et Jean, qui n’a pas de voiture, est parti avec la mienne car j’ai un contretemps et je ne peux le faire.

Comment: 1- « Celui-ci » reprend, selon la définition de ce terme, l’élément le plus récemment exprimé. Il s’agirait dans l’exemple en question de Bruno. Bruno (Celui-ci) a tendance a toujours tout exagérer.

Comment: 1 — Il n'y a pas de choix strictement logique contenu dans l'écrit (à l'oral cela devrait être beaucoup plus clair). |  2 — Exact, moins intuitif, mais plausible du point de vue des voitures :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« Le Bon Usage » confirme entièrement (ou presque) la supposition émise en ce qui concerne « 1 ».

> (**LBU § 696**)
> Le démonstratif lointain est opposé au démonstratif prochain.
> Quand le démonstratif lointain (cela, celui-là, etc.) est opposé au
> démonstratif prochain (ceci, celui-ci, etc.), le démonstratif prochain
> désigne ce qui est le plus proche dans la réalité ou dans le contexte :
> • Étendant (...] sa main droite vers le livre imprimé ouvert sur sa table et sa main gauche vers Notre-Dame [visible par la fenêtre], et promenant son triste regard du livre à l'église : / - Hélas ! dit-il, CECI tuera CELA (HUGO, N.-D. de Paris, V, 1). [Commentaire : Le livre tuera l'édifice (V, 2).]
> • Sombart oppose la sociologie occidentale naturaliste [...] à la sociologie allemande spiritualiste. CELLE-LÀ s'efforce de réduire le spirituel au psychique, le psychique au physiologique et au social CELLE-CI, au contraire, respecterait la spécificité des faits spirituels (Raym. ARON, SocioL allem. contemp., 4e éd., p. 127).
> • Estragon et Vladimir se sont remis à examiner, CELUI-LÀ [= Estragon] sa chaussure, CELUI-CI son chapeau (BECKETT, Théâtre, I, En
> attendant Godot, p. 53).
> • H s'informe [...] des études des garçons et des leçons des grandes
> demoiselles, et CEUX-LÀ et CELLES-CI, interloqués, n'ont pas toujours la présence d'esprit de répondre (YOURCENAR, Souvenirs pieux, p. 224).
> • Comp. § 220, c (adjectifs ordinaux).
> Parfois aussi le démonstratif lointain indique ce qui précède par opposition au démonstratif prochain, qui concerne ce qui suit : Je suis certain que je vous fâcherais ; alors
> CELA n'aboutira qu'à CECI : [...] j'aurai perdu une bonne camarade (PROUST, Rech., t. II,
> p. 831).

À propos du « 2 » on ne trouve rien dans LBU.

Il me semble que la distinction peut être faite dans certains cas, comme le suivant, dans lequel le type de coordination permet de trancher, apparemment, d'après  ce que je peux en juger, sans difficulté.

- Jean jouait avec son chat ; Michelle en avait un aussi, et ne voulait pas jouer avec le sien. (*On comprend qu'il n'y a pas d'ambigüité ; il s'agit du chat de Jean. Si « et » est remplacé par « mais » on comprend qu'il s'agit du chat de Michelle.*)
- Jean jouait avec son chat ; Michelle en avait un aussi, mais ne voulait pas jouer avec le sien.

La distinction n'est opérée que par la combinaison de « et » et « le sien » dans laquelle « et » prend une valeur conséquentielle, et la valeur restrictive de « mais », qui a toujours la même valeur (opposition).

Pour indiquer qu'il s'agit du chat de Michelle dans le premier paragraphe, il faut utiliser un autre pronom, ce qui annule en même temps l'idée de conséquence qui était donnée à « et ».

- Jean jouait avec son chat ; Michelle en avait un aussi, et ne voulait pas jouer avec celui-ci. (*coordination simple*)

Les considérations précédentes servent à montrer que tous les cas ne sont pas ambigus. Il y a des cas ambigus, comme celui qui a été proposé dans la seconde partie du PO.

- Jean est parti chercher Jacques avec ma voiture. Celui-ci a une voiture, mais elle  est au garage.
- Jean est parti chercher Jacques avec ma voiture. Il a du prendre la mienne parce que la sienne est au garage.

Comment: Jean jouait avec son chat ; Michelle en avait un aussi, et ne voulait pas jouer avec le sien. (On comprend qu'il n'y a pas d'ambigüité ; il s'agit du chat de Jean. Si « et » est remplacé par « mais » on comprend qu'il s'agit du chat de Michelle.)" Je ne suis pas d’accord avec vous sur ce point. Je trouve que cette phrase avec « le sien » n’est pas correcte si l’on considère que ce pronom possessif est attaché à Jean et renvoie à son chat. (1 de 2)

Comment: Il faudrait plutôt écrire « celui de Jean ». En revanche la phrase serait juste et claire si le pronom possessif était attaché à Michelle et renvoyait à son chat. Selon moi et logiquement, un pronom possessif devrait être attaché au nom le plus récemment exprimé. (2 de 2)

Comment: @Germaine LeBrun En effet, on peut argumenter qu'aucun principe ne permet vraiment de choisir l'interprétation de « et » comme marqueur de conséquence, et la coordination simple résulte en un sens tout à fait acceptable. J'admets qu'après plus ample avis, il faudra probablement reconnaitre cette construction comme ambigüe. Néanmoins, peut-on considérer  votre principe (« attaché au nom le plus récemment … ») comme absolu ? Prenons par exemple le paragraphe suivant : « Jean jouait avec son chat ; Michelle, parce qu'elle en avait un aussi, ne voulait pas jouer avec le sien, (1/2)

Comment: @Germaine LeBrun   ça aurait été compromettre son ingénuité. ». Est-ce que selon vous il est toujours nécessaire de considérer  « le sien  » comme attaché à « Michelle » ? Personnellement, je ne vois pas pourquoi la logique qui fait que  « le sien » ne peut pas avoir « chat de Michelle » comme remplacement devrait n'avoir aucun effet, pourquoi on ne pourrait pas exploiter cet élément en tant que contribution au sens.  (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

Dans les deux phrases données en exemple, le pronom de reprise est ambigu grammaticalement. Seul le sens permet de conclure qui est « celui-ci » ou à qui est la « sienne ».

> Celui-ci, celle-ci, désignent l'être ou la chose les plus proches (fonction déictique) ou représentent le nom le plus récemment exprimé

Cette explication est tellement simplifiée qu'elle est trompeuse. Le référent (être ou chose) « le plus proche » n'est pas forcément celui dont la mention est la plus proche dans le discours. Il s'agit d'une proximité dans les relations sémantiques qui peut être ambigüe.

En particulier, lorsque deux référents ont été mentionnés de manière parallèle et que « celui-ci » et « celui-là » sont utilisés en opposition, « celui-ci » désigne le référent mentionné en premier et « celui-là » désigne le deuxième. Dans ce cas, les termes sont équivalents respectivement à « l'un » et « l'autre ». Les trois phrases suivantes ont le même sens :

> Pierre et Jean ont des goûts différents. Pierre aime le rouge tandis que Jean aime le vert.
> Pierre et Jean ont des goûts différents. Celui-ci aime le rouge tandis que celui-là aime le vert.
> Pierre et Jean ont des goûts différents. L'un aime le rouge tandis que l'autre aime le vert.

Lorsque le référent n'est pas dans la même phrase, pour un pronom démonstratif, on a tendance à chercher le référent le plus proche *au même niveau grammatical*. C'est particulièrement marqué dans la deuxième phrase :

> **Jean** est parti chercher Jacques avec ma voiture. La **sienne** est au garage.

« Jacques » est un complément, donc on passe par dessus quand on cherche un référent pour le pronom dans le sujet de la deuxième phrase. On arrive donc à Jean.

C'est moins marqué avec un pronom démonstratif :

> **Jean-Daniel** n'a jamais pu supporter la personnalité excentrique de Bruno. **Il** a tendance à toujours tout exagérer.
> Jean-Daniel n'a jamais pu supporter la personnalité excentrique de **Bruno**. **Celui-ci** a tendance à toujours tout exagérer.

Ici, j'associe spontanément « il » à « Jean-Daniel » mais « celui-ci » à « Bruno ». Mais les deux sont ambigus, et si le sens l'impose, je peux changer d'avis.

Il existe en français une construction pronominale qui désigne toujours le nom le plus récemment exprimé : ***ce dernier***.

> Jean-Daniel n'a jamais pu supporter la personnalité excentrique de **Bruno**. **Ce dernier** a tendance à toujours tout exagérer.

« Ce dernier » est forcément Bruno.

Comment: Quand on a nommé deux personnes ou deux choses et qu’on emploie ensuite les pronoms celui-ci et celui-là, celui-ci se rapporte au terme le plus proche, et celui-là au terme le plus éloigné.
Démocrite et Héraclite étaient de nature bien différente : celui-ci pleurait toujours, celui-là riait sans cesse. (celui-ci se rapporte à Héraclite et celui-là à Démocrite)

Comment: https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/celui-là